# What is the difference between /proc/interrupts and /proc/softirq in Linux?

Tags: linux, proc, interrupt

`/proc/softirq` is softirq stats. Is `/proc/interrupt` both hard and soft interrupts or hard only?

I want to measure the rate of hard and soft irq's per second roughly using `watch -n 1 grep 'foo' /proc/softirq` and `watch -n 1 grep 'bar' /proc/interrupt` so I can compare the rate of hardware interrupt increase to software interrupt.

I'm wondering if I need to subtract `/proc/softirq` counts from `/proc/interrupt` to get the count of hardware IRQs because it counts both kinds or if `/proc/interrupt` is hardware only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

softirqs aren't directly related to hardware interrupts, they're the successor to "bottom halves" and the predecessor of tasklets. The (old) [Unreliable Guide to Hacking the Linux Kernel](http://kernelbook.sourceforge.net/kernel-hacking.html/basics-softirqs.html) has a brief section on the topic; I dare say there are better resources elsewhere. The list of softirqs is defined in [`include/linux/interrupt.h`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/interrupt.h#n441); you'll see they don't correspond to single hardware interrupts.

Thus you shouldn't subtract `/proc/softirq` counts from `/proc/interrupts`. The latter only counts hardware interrupts; these of course may result in softirqs being used too, but there's no easy way of determining the correlation (*e.g.* between hardware interrupts on your network adapter and `NET_RX` or `NET_TX` softirqs).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not trying to correlate them only measure them. I am aware that soft irqs and hard irqs are not directly related. I need to perf some software that uses both, so I want to see when it is running what the rate of hard and soft irq's are so I just wanted to make sure that `/proc/softirq` is soft only and `/proc/interrupt` is hard irqs only. You have confirmed this (which is what I thought to be the case).